# Initializing and running springboot project using maven in Intellij?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, lifecycle

I get a spring boot with maven project from github, which works well in my teammates computers. I am using Intellij idea and I am confused about how to run it in my computer. Should I initialize a project or can I just use the project directly by open folder?

In edit configuration part, I choose maven and the directory containing **pom.xml**. In that case it gives `noGoalsSpecified` error. So should I include a goal in command line part of edit configuration. In short, how to run the project?

Comment: Goal should probably be a Maven command like `mvn run` or something like that.

Comment: For first question, try opening the project folder directly.

Comment: Try `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start .